# Check Api Version from web server for update core data

Tags: objective-c, json, core-data

Thanks in advance for the help and be understanding if i write strange things i'm new in objective-c language.
I get json from web service and trying to store all in core-data so in case of network status off can i run app whit saved data.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.managedObjectContext =  [self managedObjectContextWithName:@"CoreData"];


    NSMutableArray * competition = [self.jsonCompetition objectForKey:@"Competition"];
    NSMutableDictionary * competizione = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i< competition.count; i++) {
        NSManagedObject * competion = [NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Competition"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        competizione = [competition objectAtIndex:i];
        [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"id"] forKeyPath:@"id"];
        [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"name"] forKeyPath:@"name"];
        [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"region"] forKeyPath:@"region"];
        NSError *error;

        if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {

            NSLog(@"Errore: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }


    }

    NSError *errore;

    if (!errore) {
        // NSLog(@"%@",_jsonDict);

    } else {

        NSLog(@"ERROR!");
    }
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&errore];

    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWWAN) {



    } else if (networkStatus == ReachableViaWiFi) {

        NSData *data = [self callWS];
        NSError *errore;

        self.jsonCompetition = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data                                                              options:kNilOptions
                                                                  error:&errore];

        self.managedObjectContext =  [self managedObjectContextWithName:@"CoreData"];


        NSMutableArray * competition = [self.jsonCompetition objectForKey:@"Competition"];
        NSMutableDictionary * competizione = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        for (int i = 0; i< competition.count; i++) {
            NSManagedObject * competion = [NSEntityDescription
                                           insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Competition"
                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

            competizione = [competition objectAtIndex:i];
            [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"id"] forKeyPath:@"id"];
            [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"name"] forKeyPath:@"name"];
            [competion setValue:[competizione objectForKey:@"region"] forKeyPath:@"region"];


            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&errore]) {

                NSLog(@"Errore: %@", [errore localizedDescription]);
            }


        }

        [self.managedObjectContext save:&errore];
        if (!error) {
            // NSLog(@"%@",_jsonDict);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR!");
        }

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entityCompetizione = [NSEntityDescription
                                       entityForName:@"Competition" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityCompetizione];
        NSArray *arrayCompetizioni = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errore];


    } else  {



        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entityCompetizione = [NSEntityDescription
                                                   entityForName:@"Competition" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entityCompetizione];

        NSArray *arrayCompetizioni = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&errore];



    }

    FirstViewController * fVC = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = fVC;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
```

In json i have a key whit ApiVersion,there is a way to check if core-data need to be updated whit the new version of json (in case of network status is on )??
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You save the previous ApiVersion to `NSUserDefaults`:

```
NSNumber *currentApiVersion = ...; //You get the version here from JSON

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentApiVersion forKey:@"ApiVersion"];
```

When new data arrives, you compare with the saved value:

```
NSNumber *currentApiVersion = ...; //You get the version here from the JSON

NSNumber *previousApiVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"ApiVersion"];

if (![currentApiVersion isEqualToNumber:previousApiVersion]) {
    //Update the stored version
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:currentApiVersion forKey:@"ApiVersion"]; 

    //The Api Version is different.
}
```

Comment: Code does its job :) Thanks again!

Comment: If you're satisfied please accept the answer so others know your problem was solved.

Comment: I would not recommend using `NSUserDefaults`.  You are mixing persistence layers.  This type of information should be stored in the metadata of the `NSPersistentStore` where the server data is being stored.  This keeps your data together instead of having one piece in one format and another piece in another format.

Comment: I agree that they should be stored together, but you need a whole new entity for that.

Comment: He's referring to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSPersistentStore_Class/NSPersistentStore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004913-CH3-SW19

Comment: I see, but that means implementing your own NSPersistentStore subclass right? Never done that before, will have to try :)

Comment: No, you just access the `NSPersistentStore`, retrieve the metadata, add the new key/value and set it back to the `NSPersistentStore`.  Three lines of code.

Comment: Ok will learn better persistence in core data and 'll keep in mind all your suggestions. Thx